# T Method Syntax

Tags: c#, nopcommerce

I am exploring nopCommerce 4.0 source code and having difficulties to understand the syntax of its popular localization method "@T()".

The way to call the method is something like @T("Products.FreeShipping") and it shall return the localized string.

Is T() a method following C# syntax? If it is a C# method, why it does not have the method signature like "public Lozalizer T(string parameter1)" pattern?

And it is using "get { ... }" statements under T() method, seems to me this is more like get accessor pattern in C#, how is it possible?

I found its implemention under "NopRazorPage" class as follow:

```
    public Localizer T
    {
        get
        {
            if (_localizationService == null)
                _localizationService = EngineContext.Current.Resolve<ILocalizationService>();

            if (_localizer == null)
            {
                _localizer = (format, args) =>
                {
                    var resFormat = _localizationService.GetResource(format);
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(resFormat))
                    {
                        return new LocalizedString(format);
                    }
                    return new LocalizedString((args == null || args.Length == 0)
                        ? resFormat
                        : string.Format(resFormat, args));
                };
            }
            return _localizer;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Localizer` type is not a `class` type it is a `delegate` type. Delegates are references to functions, they can be assigned function references, and can be invoked as functions. In the code you posted the value assigned to `_localizer` is `_localizer = (format, args) => {... }` which is syntax for an anonymous function. This is why you can call it like a function, but it looks like a property.

For more details about delegates see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/using-delegates) and for anonymous methods see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/anonymous-functions)